# surface integrals parametrising

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

Find a parameterisation and compute $r_{\alpha},r_{\beta},r_{\alpha}$ x $r_{\beta}$ and the tangent plane at the point mentioned of the surface $$x^2+y^2-z^2=2y+2z$$ where $-1\leq z \leq 0$ and the point is $(1,1,0)$.

is there a technique to parametrise this?
no one teaches properly how to parametrise...

Comment: well since both $2$ and $y$ are real number I'd be surprised if $*$ means anything else than just the usual product between numbers

Comment: Ok. When parametrising it, normally for a simple example you'd just let x and y be alpha and beta right? But since our terms have squares, we cannot simply do that right? So is the best approach to let one of these variables be sin or cos? I am very new to this.

Comment: We want to avoid the plus or minus due to the squares of the variables right?

Comment: so we have x^2 + (y-1)^2 = (z +1)^2
 so x^2=(z +1)^2 - (y-1)^2

 let z+1=rsint 
 let y-1=rcost

 then x = rcot(t)

 is this correct? or a good way to parametrise it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I have no idea how to "properly" parametrize this. However, you can take $$ x^2+y^2-z^2=2y+2z $$ and turn this into $$ x^2=z^2-y^2+2y+2z. $$ Then you have an $$ x=f^+(y,z)=\sqrt{z^2-y^2+2y+2z} $$ and an $$ x=f^-(y,z)=-\sqrt{z^2-y^2+2y+2z} $$ functions.

In the half-space of the positive $x$ axis, you can have $$ \psi^+(y,z)=(f^+(y,z),y,z), $$ and in the half-space of the negative $x$ axis, you can have $$ \psi^-(y,z)=(f^-(y,z),y,z) $$ which are parametrized surfaces. You need to check for which $y$ and $z$ do we define this though, which I am too tired to right now, so I'll assume everything works fine.

Then the tangent basis vectors are $$ \left.\frac{\partial\psi^+}{\partial y}\right|_{(1,1,0)},\ \ \left.\frac{\partial\psi^+}{\partial z}\right|_{(1,1,0)} $$ and the tangent plane is, I have no idea in what form do they ask it, but it is basically the $$ \mathrm{span}\left(\left.\frac{\partial\psi^+}{\partial y}\right|_{(1,1,0)},\left.\frac{\partial\psi^+}{\partial z}\right|_{(1,1,0)}\right) $$ subspace.